# How to turn off my video and mute my microphone when joining a Zoom meeting

Tags: zoom-meeting

I have installed the Zoom application, when I'm joining a Zoom meeting by default how can I mute my microphone and turn off my video for all the meetings?

Is there any setup in the settings to apply it for all the meetings?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the **Settings** by clicking on the Zoom icon in the taskbar.

> [image: settings]

2. In the Settings window, select the **Video** option, then select the **Turn off my video when joining meeting** checkbox.

> [image: video]

3. In the Settings window, select the **Audio** option, then select the **Mute my microphone when joining a meeting** checkbox.

> [image: microphone]